# C# Garbage Collector Begin/End Callback

Tags: c#, callback, garbage-collection

I was just wondering if there is an overridable callback for the garbage collector begin/end in the .NET runtime/C#. I will also state that I have no intentions of attempting to control the GC, I am just curious.

And if not, what would be the best way to replicate this behavior?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc713687.aspx and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678056/is-there-an-event-for-when-garbage-collection-occurs-in-net may be of some help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't get notification directly in manged code because managed code is suspended (or at least not guaranteed to run your thread in case of [background GC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ee787088%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) during GC.

Options:

- You can get approximate notification with [GC.RegisterForFullGCNotification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.registerforfullgcnotification.aspx) as shown in 
  [Garbage Collection Notifications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc713687.aspx) article.
- You can watch performance counters related to GC if you need approximate time.
- You can also capture ETW events to analyze behavior off-line - [Garbage Collection ETW Events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff356162%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). There are many links on how to do that - [Windows Performance Toolkit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh162981.aspx) and SO questions like [Consuming "Event Tracing for Windows" events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384161/consuming-event-tracing-for-windows-events).
- If really necessary you can host CLR yourself and than you'll get notifications about GC - see [CLR Indie Out:Hosting CLR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163567.aspx) and [CLR Hosting - part 3](http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2005/07/24/2984.aspx). The ultimate method you want when hosting CLR to capture start/end of GC - [IHostGCManager::SuspensionStarting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms164487%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: Managed code cannot run during compactation regardless of the GC flavor. Besides this it is a really good answer.

Comment: @AloisKraus It is somewhat open question if OP wanted to measure whole begin/end or just precise suspension time... I've added link to the article that talks about difference, but one would need to read way more to know what to measure...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I was planning on logging frequency after specific tasks. Game cycles and what have you.

Comment: @Krythic perfcounters would likely be good enough - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter.aspx, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/maoni/archive/2004/06/03/148029.aspx